# Web Essentials' RTLCSS tool does not work

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, right-to-left, web-essentials

I am using Web Essentials extension with Visual Studio 2013.

I want to use Web Essentials' `CSS RTL tool`. But when I run that tool on my CSS files nothing happens.

Web Essentials don't generate any RTL file. I've discovered when a css file have css.map file, Web Essentials could generate RTL file also.

How can I generate RTL files for every CSS files?

Comment: Try disabling source maps generation, see https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/pull/1777

Comment: @MK. I disabled Generate RTL source-maps on options>WE>CSS. but still not working.

Comment: check the output window, do you get any error?

Comment: @MK. yes this error: RTLCSS: Exception occured: Cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined

Comment: This is exactly what the link in the first comment fixes, I'll explain more in my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is related to the latest web essentials package (v2.5) having an updated postcss version that enables inline source maps by default.

If you can't compile [this branch](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/WebEssentials2013/tree/f7) and use the generated package, do the following:

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Go to `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions\{webessentials}\Resources\nodejs\tools\server\services`

   where *{username}* is your username and *{webessentials}* is a random generated folder name containing web essentials files.
3. Open `srv-rtlcss.js` search for `map = result.map.toJSON();` and replace it with:

   ```
   if (typeof result.map !== 'undefined'){
     map = result.map.toJSON();
   }
   ```
4. Save the file, Open Visual Studio and Run RTLCSS.

Let me know if you need further assistance!

Comment: Thanks a million. I've applied suggested patch and every thing is working well.