# RTL Support with MaterializeCss?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, materialize

Am starting a project which needs to support Right to Left (RTL) language, the content will be loaded via JSon. I would like to use MaterializeCss as my CSS Framework with ASP.NET MVC 5.

Am wondering is it possible to switch over to RTL? Can someone please guide me in achieving this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could easily use tools such as [RTLCSS](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/rtlcss) to convert any `css` file to RTL version. Also if you are using [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) extension you could easily convert it by right clicking in any CSS file. But have a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818720/web-essentials-rtlcss-tool-do-not-work) before using Web Essentials.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wondering, have you used the RTLCSS before? :)

Comment: Yes. I always use this tool.  Since I live in a country with a RTL language.

Comment: Good to know that and many thanks for answering the question. This week am going to give a try and I hope I will be fine! :)

Comment: @skariel right, since RTLCSS generates new CSS file from the base file you cannot use the base file and its CDN.